# Tips for measuring a front door opening?

Tags: doors, installation, framing, front-door

I'm getting ready to replace my front door with a brand new pre-hung door and have some questions regarding collecting measurements.

Where exactly should I measure? I've heard people use the phrase "rough opening" but I'm not sure what exactly that means.  Is that the frame area of the house that surrounds the doorjamb?

Also, should I be measuring from the interior of the house or the exterior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only info you need to order a new door is the actual door measurement.  36"X81" for example.  The term rough opening refers to the actual stud frame opening which you cannot see or measure with the existing door jams and trim installed. If you are concerned if your rough opening is large enough, you will need to remove the interior trim to see exactly where the studs and leader are. The exterior trim (usually brickmold ) is usually part of the prehung unit and attached when you get the new door unit.